# Omnis Studio: Return more than 1 value

Tags: windows

I'm currently programming with Omnis Studio and I need your help.

I need to return more than 1 value, but Quit Method only allows 1 value.
Is there another option to return more than 1 value?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use field reference parameters where the given parameter can be changed itself inside your method.

Another way is to return a row or list variable that contains different return values. 
A list is a data structure that contains one or more columns and one or more rows. Each column can have its own data type. 
A row variable is simply a list with only one row.

```
Calculate myRow as row(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)
Quit method myRow
```

You can access the columns by name or even by number (in the sample above the columns don’t have a name):

```
Calculate mySecondVar as myRow.c2
```

In this case c2 stands for column 2 and refers to the second variable in that row.

This way you can easily return as much values as you like.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is pass parameter(s) by reference.

You can do this in Omnis by defining your method's parameter to be of type 'field reference'.

This means that instead of passing a *copy* of the value of the variable you pass, it is passing a reference to the original variable. 
So any operations performed on the field ref inside the method will actually be acting on the original variable passed in to your method.

E.g. We have a method, **$myMethod**, which has a parameter, **pRef**, of type **Field Reference**:

```
Calculate pRef as 123
Quit method "ABC"
```

We call this method from elsewhere:

```
Calculate lVar as 0
Calculate lReturn as $cinst.$myMethod(lVar)
```

After calling $myMethod, lReturn will be "ABC" and lVar will be 123.

(I hope this wasn't too late to help you)